# What is Warning 503 by SWIG?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, swig, gcc-warning

Please explain what are these warning by SWIG and how to avoid it?

```
Warning 503: Can't wrap 'operator ()' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
Warning 503: Can't wrap 'operator =' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
Warning 503: Can't wrap 'operator *' unless renamed to a valid identifier.
```

The warnings are generated when SWIG generated C++ code is compiled under Android NDK.

Comment: That's not a G++ warning, it's a SWIG warning.

Comment: I was going to say that looks more like SWIG. It's not a problem unless you want to use those operators from Java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java doesn't have an equivalent of `operator()` or `operator=` in the same sense as C++, so there's no way for SWIG to directly wrap it. Because they might be important you're shown a warning that explains they're not being wrapped. (Missing `operator=` might be particularly bad sometimes).

This code exhibits such a warning when running `swig -Wall -c++ -java`:

```
%module Sample

struct test {
  bool operator()();
};
```

But you can silence the warning and tell SWIG to expose the operator directly as a regular member function by saying something like:

```
%module Sample

%rename(something_else) operator();

struct test {
  bool operator()();
};
```

Which results in a function called `something_else` being added in place of `operator()` in the generated wrapper.

Or you can assert to SWIG that ignoring those is just fine using:

```
%ignore operator()
```

(You can also apply either of those directives less broadly by qualifying the operators with the class names).

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle overloaded operators in a special way in SWIG, if you want to use them in the target language. See [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn28).

Answer (score 1):

You can run into this warning if you have a `%rename` directive that appears before a `%template` directive for instantiating a function like so:

```
%module some_module
%rename("%(undercase)s", %$isfunction) ""; 
// equivalently  %rename("%(utitle)s", %$isfunction) "";

%inline %{
template<class T>
void MyFunction(){}
%}
// ...

%template(MyIntFunction) MyFunction<int>;
```

> warning 503: Can't wrap 'my_function< int >' unless renamed to a valid identifier

And you cannot try to anticipate the rename in your `%template`:

```
%template(MyIntFunction) my_function<int>;
```

Because then you'll get

> error : Template 'myfunction' undefined.

Which is very frustrating if you're applying global renaming rules, and you really only need to "ignore renaming" for just a few things. Unlike typemaps, rename directives live for all-time. It'd be nice to be able to turn them off, even temporarily.

The only workaround for this I've come up with is to go back to the `%rename` and update it to explicitly only match (or rather, not match) the template functions you've declared inline. Like so:

```
// don't rename functions starting with "MyFunction"
%rename("%(undercase)s", %$isfunction, notregexmatch$name="^MyFunction") "";
```

It's not perfect, but it's a workaround.

(This was all done in SWIG 4.0)